# For HBM memory READ operation, why odd bytes driven earlier than even bytes?

Tags: sdram

As the valid data coming out at the same time, why odd bytes data I/O are driven "D" 1 CK earlier?

thanks!

[image]

Comment: where are you seeing this?

Comment: From a Renasus datasheet from google. search this "REN_r10ds0281ej0001_memory_DST_20190113"